# How do I convert MachineInstr to MCInst in LLVM?

Tags: llvm, machine-instruction

I want this conversion (from `MachineInstr` to `MCInst`) in a `MachineFunctionPass`.

I know that `X86MCInstLower` converts the `MachineInstr` to `MCInst`. However, initializing `X86MCInstLower` requires an instance of `X86AsmPrinter`. `X86AsmPrinter` is in itself `MachineFunctionPass` which requires `TargetMachine &` and `std::unique_ptr<MCStreamer>` to be initiated. I cannot get `TargetMachine` from a `MachineFunction` as `MachineFunction` only returns `const TargetMachine &`. The `TargetMachine` constructor also does not have any copy-constructor from `const TargetMachine`.

Therefore, I am stuck at this point of conversion. Is there any way to run a registered pass and get its output, from within a `MachineFunctionPass`? `X86AsmPrinter` is registered under `TargetRegistry` with `RegisterAsmPrinter`. I wonder if we could utilize that.

There is a [mailing list thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/llvm-dev/jKvxSeBxMhM) regarding this. However, that doesn't address the problem finally.

Comment: Why do you need that conversion ? Why don't you just naturally get `MCInst` ?